# How can I make a botman URL button for facebook messenger that acts as a webview?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using botman as my plugin in making messenger bot. I have this code that opens a web url, but what I want is to make it a webview.
Here is my code:

```
$botman->hears('try', function ($bot) {
    $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
    $bot->reply(ListTemplate::create()
    ->useCompactView()
    ->addElement(
        Element::create('Sample Title')
            ->subtitle('Some subtitle.')
            ->image('https://sampleurl.com/images/logo.png')
            ->addButton(ElementButton::create('Sample Button')
                ->url('https://sampleurl.com')
                )
        )
    );
});
```

The code above works but it opens the url in new tab. I like it to behave like a webview just like what I created in persistent menu:

```
'persistent_menu' => [
    [
        'locale' => 'default',
        'composer_input_disabled' => 'false',
        'call_to_actions' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Sample Title',
                'type' => 'web_url',
                'url' => 'https://sampleurl.com',
                'webview_height_ratio' => 'full',
                'webview_share_button' => 'hide',
                'messenger_extensions' => true
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `enableExtensions()` method like this. It tells FB with the request to allow the webview from a button or menu.

`When you are opening the webview from the persistent menu or a button, ensure that the messenger_extensions parameter is set to true. If a user has opened the webview via a shared message, it is not required that they have talked to your bot for Messenger Extensions to work.` (From FB Docs)

```
ButtonTemplate::create('Open Webview')
        ->addButton(ElementButton::create('Click here')
             ->url(https://myurl.com/webview')
             ->enableExtensions()
        );
```